# How to improve API calling speed android with volley

Tags: java, android, api

I m building android app with JAVA and Volley to API integration.
But when I run this app, I m always see this warn:

```
D/Volley: [1137] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ]
```

As a result sometimes I can't get expected result with Volley.

```
E/Volley: [1137] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for
```

I used to use Volley for API, need faster method.

Comment: May I use other API solution such as Retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

```
private long mRequestStartTime;

public void performRequest()
{
    mRequestStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // set the request start time just before you send the request.

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, PARAMS, 
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) 
            {
                // calculate the duration in milliseconds
                long totalRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mRequestStartTime;
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
            {
                long totalRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mRequestStartTime;
            }
        });

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Normally volley does not take more time. you can check it by yourself.
Retrofit is also good method to call API.